# Spark: How to divide interval by interval

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of the following structure:

```
timeStatistics.show(10, False)

+------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+
|idByte|min(time_delta)                        |max(time_delta)                        |avg(time_delta)                       |count|
+------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+
|1002b0|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1002b1|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1002b2|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1002b3|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1002b4|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1002b5|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1002b6|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1002b7|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1004b0|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
|1004b1|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.046' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.054' DAY TO SECOND|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00.05' DAY TO SECOND|4198 |
+------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+
only showing top 10 rows
```

I want to add a column that gives me the factor by which `min(time_delta)` and `max(time_delta)` differ.

My first atttempt was to just add:

```
.withColumn("min_max_split", (F.col("max(time_delta)")/F.col("min(time_delta)")))
```

However, it seems that division of two intervals is not supported:

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`max(time_delta)` /
> `min(time_delta)`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires
> numeric type, however, '`min(time_delta)`' is of interval day to
> second type.

I thought of converting the intervals using the `unix_timestamp()` function. However, my intervals are sometimes smaller than a second, so `unix_timestamp()` would return zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which is a slight modification from @blackbishop 's answer:

```py
.withColumn("min_max_split",\
  (\
    (F.to_timestamp(F.from_unixtime(F.lit(0)))+F.col("min(time_delta)")).cast('double')\
    / (F.to_timestamp(F.from_unixtime(F.lit(0)))+F.col("max(time_delta)")).cast('double')\
  )\
)
```

Comment: You need to use `to_timestamp` not to_date

Answer (score 0):

You can add the intervals to `current_timestamp`, convert the result into double type then divide:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "min_max_split",
    (F.current_timestamp() + F.col("max(time_delta)")).cast('double') / (
                F.current_timestamp() + F.col("min(time_delta)")).cast('double')
)

df1.show(1)
#+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------------+
#|idByte|     min(time_delta)|     max(time_delta)|     avg(time_delta)|count|     min_max_split|
#+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------------+
#|1002b0|INTERVAL '0 00:00...|INTERVAL '0 00:00...|INTERVAL '0 00:00...| 4198|1.0000000000048699|
#+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: This does not really give me the factor by which min and max differ. 00:00:00.046/00:00:00.054 should be about 1.1739